# THREE js PointsMaterial not visible or blinking afterupdate on r73

Tags: three.js

I have THREE.Points with Material:

```
var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { sizeAttenuation: false,  visible: true, size: 128, color: 0xffffff, depthTest: false, depthWrite: false,  opacity: 0.5, blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending, transparent: true, map: texture } );
```

This material works fine.

When I put another THREE.Points with the similar material, this material starts to be invisible, when I have both in camera view. 
When I rotate the camera to position, where is visible only one THREE.Points, material starts to be visible again.
When is loaded and present in the camera view field some another object, or mesh, pointClouds(Points in r73) are invisible again ...

Problem starts with update to r73.

**EDIT: IT HAPENS WHEN PLANET OBJECT IS VISIBLE set visible false, and all works great...**[image]

**EDIT2 it happens only on some GPU, on INTEL HD4000/DELL NTB, error not occuring on ATI Mobility Radeon**

Comment: can you create a fiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: http://dev.exostellar.net/test_blink.php

Comment: can you explain what we are seeing and what you would like to happen?

Comment: everything works fine, but on the background, there is a POINTS element (stars). If you load the planet, stars will be not visible or blinking, when you set a planet object visible=false stars become visible

Comment: try setting frustumCulled = false on all your objects

Comment: JS changed, visually nothing changed ...